Calculating age based on an episode start date not current date?
I'm working with another person's query.
Am I right to understand the below will give me the age of the client when the query is run?
SELECT
    C.local_ur AS Local_UR,
    C.sw_ur AS SW_UR,
    -- CN.given_nm AS Given_Name,
    -- CN.surname AS Surname,
    CN.birth_dt as DOB,
    CONVERT(int, ROUND(DATEDIFF(hour, CN.birth_dt, GETDATE()) / 8766.0, 0)) AS Age,

I have a column Episode_Startdate and would like to calculate the age on the date the episode started. Is that possible?
--EPISODE
E.epd_id AS Episode_ID,
E.start_dt AS Episode_StartDate,
E.end_dt AS Episode_EndDate,


Why should I "tag my RDBMS"? - please add a tag to specify whether you're using mysql, postgresql, sql-server, oracle or db2 - or something else entirely.

What exactly are you looking for? The age in days? So if Episode_Startdate is 2024-07-01 and today is 2024-07-11, you want to subtract and get ten days? Or do you want years? A year, though, is not a precise measure, so you'd have to think about how to deal with February 29 then. And if you don't want days, but weeks or months or years, do you want an integer result or some fraction?

That calculation is NOT accurate. See https://dbfiddle.uk/gEwaCWIS  if today's month is after the birth_dt month, at best it is an approximation based on elapsed months. If today's month is before the birth_dt month then the age is overstated by a year.

Yes, you can substitute a different value where getdate() has been used. However the calculation isn't accurate. Here is a better method:
select
   YEAR(start_dt) - YEAR(birth_dt)                        --<< year comparison
    - ( CASE
                 WHEN MONTH(birth_dt) > MONTH(start_dt)   --<< month comparison
                 OR ( MONTH(birth_dt) = MONTH(start_dt)
                 AND DAY(birth_dt) > DAY(start_dt)        --<< day-of-month comparison
                  )
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as age
, birth_dt
, start_dt
from (
  select '2000-01-17' as birth_dt, '2024-07-12' as start_dt union all
  select '2000-12-17' as birth_dt, '2024-07-12' as start_dt
  ) d




Age
birth_dt
start_dt




24
2000-01-17
2024-07-12


23
2000-12-17
2024-07-12



One needs to compare the month and day values to calculate age correctly. Below are examples showing the difference:
select 
  CONVERT(int, ROUND(DATEDIFF(hour, birth_dt, GETDATE()) / 8766.0, 0)) AS Age
, birth_dt
from (
  select '2000-01-17' as birth_dt union all
  select '2000-12-17' as birth_dt
  ) d




Age
birth_dt




24
2000-01-17


24
2000-12-17



select
   YEAR(getdate()) - YEAR(birth_dt)                        --<< year comparison
    - ( CASE
                 WHEN MONTH(birth_dt) > MONTH(getdate())   --<< month comparison
                 OR ( MONTH(birth_dt) = MONTH(getdate())
                 AND DAY(birth_dt) > DAY(getdate())        --<< day-of-month comparison
                  )
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as age
, birth_dt
from (
  select '2000-01-17' as birth_dt union all
  select '2000-12-17' as birth_dt
  ) d




Age
birth_dt




24
2000-01-17


23
2000-12-17



fiddle

Thanks @adrianmaxwell I appreciate the clear response.  I've been away from my desk for a few days. I'll take some time to work through your suggestions. Thanks again
